# What is the `x2` or `x3` next to a tag in my profile?

Tags: discussion, support

[image]

Or, I guess, what is the difference between that and the number before the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number to the right of the tag is **the number of times you've posted with that tag** — questions with that tag and answers on questions with that tag. Similarly (yet substantially different) is the number on the left: the sum of votes received on the posts.

---

For example, here is one of the tags from my user page:

[image]

The right number is calculated based on the total number of interactions I've had with the tag. In the example above, I have asked [5 questions tagged with osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A37797+%5Bosx%5D+is%3Aquestion) and [178 answers to questions tagged with osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A37797+%5Bosx%5D+is%3Aanswer). Therefore, I have interacted with the osx tag 183 times, hence the number shown on the right.

The number on the left is the sum of the votes that I have received for my posts. In the example above, [4 questions have accumulated 12 votes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A37797+%5Bosx%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1) and [134 answers have accumulated 301 votes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A37797+%5Bosx%5D+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1). Therefore, my total score for the osx tag is 313, hence the number shown on the left.

Comment: So is the number to the right only for questions, and the number to the left for both questions and answers? Or do both sides take both Q and A into account?

Comment: @dwightk Edited to add clarification

Answer (score 0):

The `x` is how many times you have used or interacted that tag. Let's say i use the tag `recovery` like 5 times. It would say `recovery x5`.

---

[image]